# PostgreSQL connection (through pg-promise) service problem

Tags: moleculer

I have created the following `db_postgres` service which works fine.

**db_postgres.service.js**

```
"use strict";

const Promise = require('bluebird');

const initOptions = {
    promiseLib: Promise,
    capSQL:     true
};

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

const cn_postgres = {
    host:     'localhost',
    port:      5432,
    database: 'db_name',
    user:     'user_name',
    password: 'user_password',
    ...
};

var db_postgres = null;

module.exports = {
    name: "db_postgres",
    version: "",
    mixins: [],
    hooks: {},
    settings: {},
    metadata: {},
    dependencies: [],

    actions: {
        getUsers() {
            db_postgres.any('SELECT * FROM user')
                .then(data => {
                    return console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return console.log(error);
                });
        },
    },

    methods: {},
    events: {},
    created() {},

    async started() {
        return db_postgres = await pgp(cn_postgres);
    },

    async stopped() {
        if (db_postgres) {
            return db_postgres.$pool.end();
        }
    }
}
```

**Case:**

- I have a large number of actions.
- I would like to create more instances of this service,
  but unfortunately, it is **not** possible since I get a warning/error
  about establishing a new connection that already exists.
- I do not wish to use any ORM-based solution.
- I wish to avoid using any wrapper function(s) and maintain
  a DRY manner as much as possible.

**Question:**
What is the simplest and easiest way to do that?

**My effort:**

- I removed the `getUsers()` action from `db_postgres` service.
- I created a new `queries` service as follows:

**queries.service.js**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    name: "queries",
    version: "",
    mixins: [db_postgres],
    hooks: {},
    settings: {},
    metadata: {},
    dependencies: ["db_postgres"],

    actions: {
        getUsers() {
            db_postgres.any('SELECT * FROM user')
                .then(data => {
                    return console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return console.log(error);
                });
        },
    },

    methods: {},
    events: {},
    created() {},
    async started() {},
    async stopped() {}
}
```

**Problems:**

- When I add `"db_postgres"` in `dependencies` and run `npm run dev`
  ie `moleculer-runner --env --hot --repl services`,
  the `db_postgres` service is being registered normally.
  But, `queries` service is never. The flow in terminal freezes and cursor is blinking.
  Why?
- Next, when I also add `db_postgres` in `mixins` I get the following error
  `Failed to load service '.../services/queries.service.js' ReferenceError: db_postgres is not defined`
  Why?

Tia

Answer (score 0):

You should load `db_postgres` with require and use as a mixin, not as dependency.

Comment: In this case, when I run `call queries.getUsers`  I get: `db_postgres.any is not a function...`. I suspect that by saying "... use as a mixin", you mean "forget **service schema** syntax and use the **classic** way" as it is done in `db.mixin.js` in **conduit** example. Correct?